# How to get file name and file Type using inputStream?

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

guys i'm using inputStream for file Download . now i want to pass fileName and fileType into DefaultStreamedContent .now how can i find fileName and FileType using inputStream .

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream,**fileType,fileName**);
```

Comment: why don't you use `fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream);` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This information can't be extracted from `InputStream`. This information can only be extracted based on the `filePath` (and with little help of `java.io.File` to easily get the filename).

```
File file = new File(filePath);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
String fileName = file.getName();
String fileType = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getEexternalContext().getMimeType(fileName);
fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, fileType, fileName);
```

The `ExternalContext#getMimeType()` is determined based on `<mime-mapping>` entries in `web.xml`. The servletcontainer has already a whole bunch definied by itself (in Tomcat, check `/conf/web.xml`) but you can extend and override it by (re)defining them in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/web.xml` like as follows for an XLSX type:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xlsx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```